# Radial gradient image generator

Tags: performance, image, rust, graphics

A function to create a radial gradient from one rgb colour to another and using rayon to improve performance. Are there better way to convert between some of the types / any obvious performance improvements I could implement?

```
use image::RgbImage;
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn radial_gradient(
    geometry: (i32, i32),
    inner_color: Vec<u8>,
    outer_color: Vec<u8>,
    foreground_size: i32,
) -> RgbImage {
    let mut background: RgbImage = RgbImage::new(geometry.0 as u32, geometry.1 as u32);

    let distance = |x: i32, y: i32| (((x).pow(2) + (y).pow(2)) as f64).sqrt();

    // The background will adapt to the foreground size so that the inner_color will be at the edges of the art
    // and not just at the centre of the image
    let max_dist =
        distance((geometry.0 / 2) as i32, (geometry.1 / 2) as i32) - (foreground_size / 2) as f64;

    background
        .par_chunks_exact_mut(3)
        .enumerate()
        .for_each(|(pixel_num, pixel)| {
            let x_dist = i32::try_from(pixel_num).unwrap() % geometry.0 - geometry.0 / 2;
            let y_dist = i32::try_from(pixel_num).unwrap() / geometry.0 - geometry.1 / 2;
            let scaled_dist = (distance(x_dist, y_dist) - (foreground_size / 2) as f64) / max_dist;

            for (i, subpix) in pixel.iter_mut().enumerate() {
                *subpix = ((outer_color[i] as f64 * scaled_dist)
                    + (inner_color[i] as f64 * (1.0 - scaled_dist)))
                    as u8
            }
        });
    background
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things I changed:

- `x * x` is faster than `x.pow(2)`
- `f64` is way overkill for this, use `f32`
- Replace `Vec<u8>` inputs with `[u8; 3]`
- Use fused-multiply-add to implement `lerp`
- Move `distance` to separate function for readability
- Move all constant values out of the loop
- Pixel is too small for efficient parallelization, parallelize over rows instead. Now that we have `.enumerate` as row id, use simple counter to get column id.

Here's my benchmark suite:

```
use image::RgbImage;
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn radial_gradient_orig(
    geometry: (i32, i32),
    inner_color: Vec<u8>,
    outer_color: Vec<u8>,
    foreground_size: i32,
) -> RgbImage {
    let mut background: RgbImage = RgbImage::new(geometry.0 as u32, geometry.1 as u32);

    let distance = |x: i32, y: i32| (((x).pow(2) + (y).pow(2)) as f64).sqrt();

    // The background will adapt to the foreground size so that the inner_color will be at the edges of the art
    // and not just at the centre of the image
    let max_dist =
        distance((geometry.0 / 2) as i32, (geometry.1 / 2) as i32) - (foreground_size / 2) as f64;

    background
        .par_chunks_exact_mut(3)
        .enumerate()
        .for_each(|(pixel_num, pixel)| {
            let x_dist = i32::try_from(pixel_num).unwrap() % geometry.0 - geometry.0 / 2;
            let y_dist = i32::try_from(pixel_num).unwrap() / geometry.0 - geometry.1 / 2;
            let scaled_dist = (distance(x_dist, y_dist) - (foreground_size / 2) as f64) / max_dist;

            for (i, subpix) in pixel.iter_mut().enumerate() {
                *subpix = ((outer_color[i] as f64 * scaled_dist)
                    + (inner_color[i] as f64 * (1.0 - scaled_dist))) as u8
            }
        });
    background
}

#[inline]
fn lerp(pct: f32, a: f32, b: f32) -> f32 {
    pct.mul_add(b - a, a)
}

#[inline]
fn distance(x: i32, y: i32) -> f32 {
    ((x * x + y * y) as f32).sqrt()
}

fn radial_gradient_improved_1(
    geometry: (u32, u32),
    inner_color: [u8; 3],
    outer_color: [u8; 3],
    foreground_size: u32,
) -> RgbImage {
    let mut background: RgbImage = RgbImage::new(geometry.0 as u32, geometry.1 as u32);

    // The background will adapt to the foreground size so that the inner_color will be at the edges of the art
    // and not just at the centre of the image
    let center = (geometry.0 / 2, geometry.1 / 2);
    let foreground_half = (foreground_size / 2) as f32;
    let max_dist = distance(center.0 as i32, center.1 as i32) - foreground_half;

    let inner_color = inner_color.map(|el| el as f32);
    let outer_color = outer_color.map(|el| el as f32);

    background
        .par_chunks_exact_mut(3)
        .enumerate()
        .for_each(|(pixel_num, pixel)| {
            let pixel_num = pixel_num as u32;
            let pos_y = pixel_num / geometry.0;
            let pos_x = pixel_num % geometry.0;

            let dist_x = pos_x as i32 - center.0 as i32;
            let dist_y = pos_y as i32 - center.1 as i32;
            let scaled_dist = (distance(dist_x, dist_y) - foreground_half) / max_dist;

            pixel[0] = lerp(scaled_dist, inner_color[0], outer_color[0]) as u8;
            pixel[1] = lerp(scaled_dist, inner_color[1], outer_color[1]) as u8;
            pixel[2] = lerp(scaled_dist, inner_color[2], outer_color[2]) as u8;
        });
    background
}

fn radial_gradient_improved_2(
    geometry: (u32, u32),
    inner_color: [u8; 3],
    outer_color: [u8; 3],
    foreground_size: u32,
) -> RgbImage {
    let mut background: RgbImage = RgbImage::new(geometry.0 as u32, geometry.1 as u32);

    // The background will adapt to the foreground size so that the inner_color will be at the edges of the art
    // and not just at the centre of the image
    let center = (geometry.0 / 2, geometry.1 / 2);
    let foreground_half = (foreground_size / 2) as f32;
    let max_dist = distance(center.0 as i32, center.1 as i32) - foreground_half;
    let one_over_max_dist = 1.0 / max_dist;

    let inner_color = inner_color.map(|el| el as f32);
    let outer_color = outer_color.map(|el| el as f32);

    background
        .par_chunks_exact_mut(3 * geometry.0 as usize)
        .enumerate()
        .for_each(|(pos_y, row)| {
            for pos_x in 0..geometry.0 {
                let dist_x = pos_x as i32 - center.0 as i32;
                let dist_y = pos_y as i32 - center.1 as i32;
                let scaled_dist = (distance(dist_x, dist_y) - foreground_half) * one_over_max_dist;

                let pixel_pos = (pos_x * 3) as usize;
                let pixel = &mut row[pixel_pos..(pixel_pos + 3)];

                pixel[0] = lerp(scaled_dist, inner_color[0], outer_color[0]) as u8;
                pixel[1] = lerp(scaled_dist, inner_color[1], outer_color[1]) as u8;
                pixel[2] = lerp(scaled_dist, inner_color[2], outer_color[2]) as u8;
            }
        });
    background
}

const NUM_ITER: usize = 50;

fn main() {
    {
        let duration = (0..NUM_ITER)
            .into_iter()
            .map(|_| {
                let t = std::time::Instant::now();
                let _img =
                    radial_gradient_orig((1300, 1024), vec![255, 128, 0], vec![0, 128, 255], 30);
                t.elapsed()
            })
            .min()
            .unwrap();
        println!("Original: {} ms", duration.as_secs_f32() * 1000.0);
    }
    {
        let duration = (0..NUM_ITER)
            .into_iter()
            .map(|_| {
                let t = std::time::Instant::now();
                let _img =
                    radial_gradient_improved_1((1300, 1024), [255, 128, 0], [0, 128, 255], 30);
                t.elapsed()
            })
            .min()
            .unwrap();
        println!("Improved 1: {} ms", duration.as_secs_f32() * 1000.0);
    }
    {
        let duration = (0..NUM_ITER)
            .into_iter()
            .map(|_| {
                let t = std::time::Instant::now();
                let _img =
                    radial_gradient_improved_2((1300, 1024), [255, 128, 0], [0, 128, 255], 30);
                t.elapsed()
            })
            .min()
            .unwrap();
        println!("Improved 2: {} ms", duration.as_secs_f32() * 1000.0);
    }

    radial_gradient_orig((1300, 1024), vec![255, 128, 0], vec![0, 128, 255], 30)
        .save("img_orig.bmp")
        .unwrap();
    radial_gradient_improved_1((1300, 1024), [255, 128, 0], [0, 128, 255], 30)
        .save("img_imp1.bmp")
        .unwrap();
    radial_gradient_improved_2((1300, 1024), [255, 128, 0], [0, 128, 255], 30)
        .save("img_imp2.bmp")
        .unwrap();
}
```

```
> cargo run --release
Original: 5.9073 ms
Improved 1: 4.4981 ms
Improved 2: 2.6811001 ms
```

Comment: Thanks for the code review it helps a lot. I did at one point try to calculate in chunks larger than per pixel although I didn't manage to get a significant speed up. Do you have any tips for how to know what can be efficiently parallelized?

Comment: Not really... It's usually trial and error. In an educated way, meaning, if possible, you introduce a hyper parameter for the chunk size and then plot speedup vs chunk size to get a feeling for it. But I don't know if rayon already does chunking internally, I don't think it spawned a work packet for every pixel, that would have been way slower. I could imagine that it just splits the work by number of threads and then does workstealing if one thread is faster. So it's really just trial and error.

Comment: I primarily did it to get rid of the division and modulo operator to compute the pixel coordinate. Division and modulo are amongst the slowest operations that exist.

Comment: That's also why I introduced the `one_over_max_dist` variable. Float multiplication is waaay faster than float division.

Comment: Although compilers nowadays are really smart and apply many of those optimizations automatically, so it comes really down to benchmarking to see what has an effect and what doesn't.

Comment: To optimize further, i think we would have to step into SSE/AVX territory.

Comment: Ah yeah that might also be a reason why bigger chunk sizes might improve performance: for simple single threaded for loops, the compiler is able to generate SIMD (SSE/AVX) instructions automatically.